# OpenShift - How to install Microsoft ODBC Drivers for Linux

Tags: python, openshift, pyodbc

My pyramid application connect to MS SQL server using pyodbc driver. For connecting to DB, it uses Microsoft ODBC driver for Linux (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36437).  Now how can I install those drivers on openshift

Thanks
Aniruddha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone may be able to provide a more thorough answer, but I thought this might help get you started:

While I've never installed it myself... you should be able to download the zip/tar file in your  `~/app-root/data/` on your gear and then be able to extract it. Depending on how/where it installs you might be able to successfully get it implemented.